# I remove proxy from git but still showing the error how to resolve it?

Tags: linux, git, github, proxy

My git is stuck whenever now I try pull,push or clone I remove the proxy but still no positive response from git.

**Last time I used this command for proxy:**

```
git config --global http.proxy 172.16.0.2:8080
```

**I try these commands:**

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
```

but still getting this response when I clone the repository or want to pull or push!

```
badar:DSA Lab Tasks$ git clone https://github.com/badarshahzad/SEGP_Group10.git
Cloning into 'SEGP_Group10'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/badarshahzad/SEGP_Group10.git/': Failed to connect to 172.16.0.2 port 8080: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using these comands

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
```

These two commands work for me after --unset the proxy

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo reboot
```

After that my git commands start working